# What does RubyMonk's calculate method do?

Tags: ruby, methods

I'm learning Ruby on RubyMonk right now and am struggling with the code below: the `calculate` method -> `def calculate(*arguments)`. Is it possible that you can explain to me each line of code? I think I know what each code line's syntax, but the logic doesn't make any sense to me?

```
def add(*numbers)
    numbers.inject(0) { |sum, number| sum + number }  
end

def subtract(*numbers)
  sum = numbers.shift
  numbers.inject(sum) { |sum, number| sum - number }  
end

def calculate(*arguments)
  # if the last argument is a Hash, extract it 
  # otherwise create an empty Hash
  options = arguments[-1].is_a?(Hash) ? arguments.pop : {}
  options[:add] = true if options.empty?
  return add(*arguments) if options[:add]
  return subtract(*arguments) if options[:subtract]
end
```

for example, the `options` is killing me...I don't know what result returns from the two lines...

Thank you so much!

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions/253896#comment17104_253896

Answer (score 1):

```
options = arguments[-1].is_a?(Hash) ? arguments.pop : {}
```

arguments is an array.  A negative array index starts counting from the end of the array, with -1 being the last element.  So arguments[-1] is the last argument passed to the method.  is_a?(Hash) tests if the argument is a hash.  '?' and ':' make up the ternary operator.  If the last argument is a hash, pop it from the array.  If it is not, then just give us an empty hash.

```
options[:add] = true if options.empty?
```

This line is equivalent to:

```
if options.empty?
  options[:add] = true
end
```

What it's saying here is that if the caller didn't specify what operation they wanted, then assume they wanted to perform addition.

```
return add(*arguments) if options[:add]
```

Call the add method and return the result if options[:add].  If the caller specified addition, or if the caller did not specify any operation, then this line will be executed and the method will return here.  Nothing else will be executed.

```
return subtract(*arguments) if options[:subtract]
```

Call the subtract method and return the result if options[:subtract].  If the caller specified subtraction (and did *not* specify addition), then this line will be executed and the method will return here.  Nothing else will be executed.

Note that it's possible to reach the end of this method without triggering either of the explicit return statements, basically by passing { :operation_not_supported => true } as the last argument.  In which case, you get ruby's implicit return, which would be the value of the last line executed.  Which would be the one that retrieves the options hash from the argument array.  Short version:  specifying an unsupported operation when you call this method will have the calculate method return your options hash.

Comment: Thank you so much! Will read it tomorrow and see if I have additional questions! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's just an implementation of this usage:

```
calculate(1, 2, 3, add: true)       #=> 6  (1 + 2 + 3)
calculate(1, 2, 3, subtract: true)  #=> -4 (1 - 2 - 3)
calculate(1, 2, 3)                  #=> 6 (option defaults to {add: true})
```